# How to parse IP address in P4

Tags: networking, switching

I have a basic task to connect some nodes to switch and let them communicate only with even-to-even and odd-to-odd IP addresses.

**Scenario topology**:
The starting point is an access network with full L2 connectivity based on a `<DestMAC,OutputPort>` table implemented on P4 switch.

**Goal**
Write a P4 code that creates two network slices, one enabling communication only between nodes with even IP addresses
and the other enabling communication only between nodes with odd IP addresses

```
header ipv4_t {
    bit<4>    version;
    bit<4>    ihl;
    bit<8>    diffserv;
    bit<16>   totalLen;
    bit<16>   identification;
    bit<3>    flags;
    bit<13>   fragOffset;
    bit<8>    ttl;
    bit<8>    protocol;
    bit<16>   hdrChecksum;
    ip4Addr_t srcAddr;
    ip4Addr_t dstAddr;
}

struct headers {
    ethernet_t   ethernet;
    ipv4_t       ipv4; //tay
}

/**SOME CODE*/

/*************************************************************************
**************  I N G R E S S   P R O C E S S I N G   *******************
*************************************************************************/

control MyIngress(inout headers hdr,
                  inout metadata meta,
                  inout standard_metadata_t standard_metadata) {

    action drop() {
        mark_to_drop(standard_metadata);
    }

    action check_ip_odd_even(){
        //TODO:
    }

    action forward_to_port(bit<9> egress_port) {
        standard_metadata.egress_spec = egress_port;
    }

    table dmac_forward {
        key = {
            hdr.ethernet.dstAddr: exact;
        }
        actions = {
            //ipv4_forward;
            forward_to_port;
            drop;
        }
        size = 8;
        default_action = drop;
    }

    apply {
        // if(hdr.ipv4.srcAddr & 1 == 1){
        //  //it's odd
        //     //dmac_forward.apply();
        // }

        // else {
        //     // it's even 
        //     dmac_forward.apply();
        // }
        
        //10.0.0.13 vs 10.0.0.11 
        if (hdr.ipv4.srcAddr == 0x0a00000D && hdr.ipv4.dstAddr == 0x0a00000b){
            dmac_forward.apply();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to `and` with `1` so if it's 1 I would say it's odd but my solution didn't work. I also tried with exactly given IP addresses but this is not the general solution.

Any suggestion, please?

Comment: "_I have a basic task to connect some nodes to switch and let them communicate only with even-to-even and odd-to-odd IP addresses._" Switches are transparent devices that do not look at the layer-3 IP packets, only the layer-2 frames. Routers strip the frames from the packets and route by IP address.

Comment: @RonMaupin I am sorry but this doesn't really help me with anything. Can you see my edit that explains the goal and the scenario?